# Compare 2 objects of the same type on the id field so I know to update or save the object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have 2 list of object of type `CustomerEntity`.
They are of the same entity.

CustomerEntity  contains 2 fields.

```
CustomerEntity
    ID
    Name

List<Customerntity> incomingCustomer
List<CustomerEntity> dbCustomers
```

I am having trouble comparing the 2 list of objects on the `Id`. If the incomingCustomer Ids exists  in  dbCustomers then add the object to `List<CustomerEntity> customersToUpdate`.

I have tried linq and for each statements, but unable to come up with an elegant solution.

Tried:

```
   var tmp = incomingCustomer.Where(x =>
    dbCustomers.Any(z => x.Id == z.Id)
    && !dbCustomers.Any(z => x.Id == z.Id));
```

Also tired foreach loops which was a disaster

Thank for your help

Comment: Please update your question with your best attempt at resolving this yourself, and clarify why that approach isn't working (we need more info other than the fact that you don't think it's elegant)

Comment: Is this a kind of upsert operation (update or insert) ?

Comment: This is a update or insert operation. Update if id already exist else insert if id does not exist

Comment: Why do you have the `&& !dbCustomers.Any(z => x.Id == z.Id)` in your condition? That is the opposite of the first condition, so it's basically saying "Where(x => `true && false`)"
 which will never be true so no items will ever be returned.

Comment: `var customersToUpdate = dbCustomers.Where(dbCust => incomingCustomer.Any(inCust => dbCust.Id == inCust.Id)).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken an sample

```
// These are the class structure
    class dbCustomer : CustomerEntity
    {

    }


    class incomingCustomer : CustomerEntity
    {
        
    }

    class CustomerEntity
    {
          public int Id { get; set; }
    }

// Sample data in list
    IList<dbCustomer> dbCustomers = new List<dbCustomer>
    {
             new dbCustomer{ Id = 2},
             new dbCustomer{ Id = 3},
             new dbCustomer{ Id = 4}
    };

    IList<incomingCustomer> incomingCustomer = new List<incomingCustomer>
    {
            new incomingCustomer{ Id = 1},
            new incomingCustomer{ Id = 2},
            new incomingCustomer{ Id = 4}
     };

// your query
List<CustomerEntity> customersToUpdate = dbCustomers.Where(l1 => incomingCustomer.Any(l2 => l2.Id == l1.Id)).ToList<CustomerEntity>();
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you recommend the best way to learn LINQ?

Comment: Once, you have read all the basics. Best would be to search LINQ questions on Stackoverflow which are already answered and practice them. and try answering new ones as well